# Do un-contracted workers have to fill out W4?

Tags: united-states, ethics, law, taxes

I worked via verbal agreement, and have been paid with a check (from the business, not a personal check).  I am now being asked to fill out a W4, but from my experience with this company I am very wary of giving personal information (my SS# etc.)
 What consequences do I face (if any) if I don't fill out the form? -- I was paid under $3000, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The company has to treat you one of two ways:

- If you are an employee they have to get a W-4 from you. This will let them collect and forward to the proper government authorities your income tax and, FICA.
- If you are not a employee then you are a contractor. They will need a w-9 from from you so that they can tell the IRS who they paid. They will need to issue you a 1099 at the end of the year. The requirement for the 1099 occurs one they paid you more than $600 in a year.

> but from my experience with this company I am very wary of giving
>   personal information (my SS# etc.)

Either form will require your SSN or other form of taxpayer ID. The W-2 or 1099 at the end of the year will trigger the IRS into looking for matching information from you.

> What consequences do I face (if any) if I don't fill out the form?

If you [fail to provide the correct number](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw9.pdf):

> **Failure to furnish TIN.** If you fail to furnish your correct TIN to a requester, you are
>   subject to a penalty of $50 for each such failure  unless your failure
>   is due to reasonable cause and not to willful neglect

So $50 doesn't seem that bad.

But if you don't supply a number or if the IRS tell the company you supplied an incorrect number then you will trigger backup withholding.

> **Backup Withholding**
>
> **What is backup withholding?**  Persons making certain
>   payments to you  must under certain conditions withhold and pay to the
>   IRS 28% of such  payments. This is called “backup withholding.” 
>   Payments that may be  subject to backup withholding include interest,
>   tax-exempt interest,  dividends, broker and barter exchange
>   transactions, rents, royalties,  nonemployee pay, payments made in
>   settlement of payment card and  third party network transactions, and
>   certain payments from fishing boat  operators. Real estate
>   transactions are not subject to backup  withholding.
>
> You will not be
>   subject to backup withholding on payments you  receive if you give the
>   requester your correct TIN, make the proper  certifications, and
>   report all your taxable interest and dividends on your  tax return.
>
> **Payments you receive will be subject to backup withholding if**:
>   1. You do not furnish your TIN to the requester,
>   2. You do not certify your TIN when required (see the instructions for  Part II for details),
>   3. The IRS tells the requester that you furnished an incorrect TIN,
>   4. The IRS tells you that you are subject to backup withholding  because you did not report all your interest and dividends on your tax 
>   return (for reportable interest and dividends only), or
>   5. You do not certify to the requester that you are not subject to  backup withholding under 4 above (for reportable interest and dividend
>   accounts opened after 1983 only).

Note with the new tax law the 28% figure is now 24%.

So any future payments to you will have 24% withheld and sent to the IRS.

Comment: For those in the defense industry looking to get a clearance, being on the bad side of the IRS, isn’t a good thing.  Why do I me mention this fact, well lots of people ask about security clearances here it seems, and to show backup withholding isn’t a good thing.